# iOS - How can I put special characters (music notation) in a UILabel?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to create a label with some unicode text and a music note. The notes are shown below:

[image]

I have tried:

```
titleLabel.text = @" title + &#9835;";
```

but that results in:

[image]

I must be doing something dumb.. Any advice welcome.

Comment: try \u9835   - That should escape the unicode characters

Comment: close but that returns a chinese symbol :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number column in your table actually contains HTML/SGML/XML entities with decimal values. A unicode escape sequence in NSString takes the hexadecimal value, so your note `&#9835;` would be the hex value 0x266b to be used like this

```
titleLabel.text = @" title \u266b";
```

Comment: perfect. Thanks!! I would have spent hours tracking this.. SO rocks.

Comment: Is there a decent list of Unicode escape sequences? unicode.org and others are quite obtuse.

Comment: http://unicode-table.com seems like an ok resource. Note that symbols may be missing from the font you use.

Answer (score 0):

Hit cmd+cntrl+space in Xcode, and search for 'note'. There are some u may use. Just double click one and it will be written where your cursor is in the code.